# ImageMagick/IMagick renders groups in SVGs offset

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I've got an app that takes an SVG as input and converts to a PNG as output. I've run into a problem where if the SVG has grouped items using the  tag, that content gets rendered way off to the right and down on the SVG.

This only happens using IMagick. If I open the SVG in Illustrator or Inkscape for PC, it looks fine. Here's what the SVG code looks like:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="2400px" height="3200px" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <g id="SvgjsG1048" transform="rotate(0 1200 1600) translate(30.927835051559143 41.23711340207863) scale(0.9742268041237008 0.9742268041237009) " x="30.927835051559143" y="41.23711340207863">
      <image id="SvgjsImage1049" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="aerosmith.png" width="2400" height="3200"></image>
   </g>
</svg>
```

and here's the code I'm using to pull in and render:

```
// setup the SVG
$svg_front = new Imagick();
$svg_front->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
$svg_front->readImage($json->imageFront); // pull in the SVG image

// convert the SVG to PNG @ 200 dpi - yes, it works!
$svg_front->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);
$svg_front->setImageResolution(200,200);

// set image format
$svg_front->setImageFormat('png');

// render the SVG
echo $svg_front;
```

Nothing out of the ordinary here. Removing the code to set the resolution doesn't make any difference, and I've tried resetPage to no effect as well.

Now, if I remove the  tag and leave the image in there, then the SVG renders with no issue. However, I can't control whether the app sends grouped items or not, and IMagick needs to render it no matter what.

Here's the image when it gets rendered to PNG with a  tag in the SVG: http://brainboxinteractive.com/bad-svg.png

And here's what is should look like: http://brainboxinteractive.com/what-it-should-look-like.png

Inkscape is installed on the server, so IMagick/ImageMagick is using it so I'm not sure where to start debugging and fixing this issue. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you convert it through the command line ImageMagick tools e.g. something like `convert test.svg test_output.png` ?

Comment: I can't use the command line as this is a web app, and I need to keep the reference to the object so I can use it to create composite images.

I'm getting JSON data posted to the app, and it's using the data (including the link to the SVG) to create mockup images.

SVGs are also default 96 dpi if I'm not mistaken, and the PNG needs to be 2400x3200 at 200dpi. So I have that requirement as well.

Comment: I didn't suggest using the command line in the application. I said you need to test the command line to identify exactly what is causing the issue.

Comment: Most SVG delegate libraries will not allow `xlink` image imports. This is at the system security level. Either patch & recompile the `rsvg` library, or use ImageMagick's internal `msvg:` engine.